# Add ContextMenuStipItem at Run time

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a little application that run in the system tray.  There is a MenuStrip that show when the user right clicks on the icon in the tray.  One of the buttons opens a form where a user can add new buttons to the strip.  I can create the buttons but when a button is added the path gets set for all other buttons.

Example:
I create a new button name "Documents". I set the path to My Documents folder.  That works.
Then I add another button named "C".  I set the path to "C:\".  It sets the path and opens C:\, but it also sets the Documents button to "C:\" as well.

There are 2 text-boxes on the form, one for the name and one for the path.  The name is what shows up in the menu, and the path is what should open when the user clicks the button in the menu.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim newItem As New ToolStripMenuItem
    newItem.Text = NameBox.Text
    AddHandler newItem.Click, AddressOf buttonClick
    ContextMenuStrip1.Items.Add(newItem)

End Sub

Private Sub buttonClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", PathBox.Text)
End Sub
```

I understand what is happening, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Its setting all the buttons click event to buttonClick, so how do a create a new sub for each button that handles its own click event at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PathBox.Text` returns the *current* value of the textbox.

Instead, you should add a lambda expression and capture the original value in its closure:

```
Dim path As String = PathBox.Text

AddHandler newItem.Click, Sub
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", path)
End Sub
```